# Centering inputs with css and bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a form that I want to center on the page. The labels are centered but for some reason, I can't center the input with the form-control class.

It is rendering like this right now...

[EDIT: the `display: block;` inside form-control is causing the issue. Not sure why, how can I disable it]

[image]

```css
#centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id='centered'>
          <span class="form-group">
            <h5 class="label">Email</h5>
            <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text">
          </span>
        <span class="form-group">
          <h5 class="label">Name</h5>
          <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text">
        </span>
        <span class="form-group">
          <h5 class="label">Create A Password</h5>
          <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text">
        </span>
        <span class="form-group">
          <h5 class="label">Confirm Password</h5>
          <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text">
        </span>
        <input class="form-group-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="confirm_terms"> <strong>Agree to terms</strong>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your example shows the form centered. Please ensure you have provided a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also I'm noticing that you are reusing `id="form-group"` which is not advised as id names are supposed to be unique (1 only)

Comment: Nt sure why the example works but the actual code does not. I included a picture of the actual output.

Comment: I see the display: block; in form-control is causing the problem. How can I turn that off. Not sure why that is causing the problem.

Comment: Because `d-block` make an element `block`. `block` elements are aligned left by default.  Btw, `span` can't contain `h5`, a block element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change the `display` property of all `form-control` inside that div:

```
 #centered .form-control {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't get it. I actually made a new class called sexy-input. I put all the form-control attributes into it except `display: block` but that seems very dirty I was hoping for something cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

Use the class `mx-auto`

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
#centered {
  text-align: center;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id='centered' class="mx-auto">
          <span class="form-group">
            <h5 class="label">Email</h5>
            <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text">
          </span>
        <span class="form-group">
          <h5 class="label">Name</h5>
          <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text">
        </span>
        <span class="form-group">
          <h5 class="label">Create A Password</h5>
          <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text">
        </span>
        <span class="form-group">
          <h5 class="label">Confirm Password</h5>
          <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text">
        </span>
        <input class="form-group-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="confirm_terms"> <strong>Agree to terms</strong>
  </div>
```